# Error in predict.lm in R: factor as.factor(daily) has new level 2

Tags: r, statistics, prediction

I built a linear regression model as below:

```
 ApacheData$daily <- cut(ApacheData$daily, breaks=c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9,3000))
 ApacheData$age <- cut(ApacheData$age, breaks=c(0,44,65,150))

 fit <-lm(tomorrow_apache~ as.factor(state_today)
         +as.numeric(daily_creat) 
         + as.factor(daily)
         + as.factor(age)
         +as.numeric(apache3) 
         + as.factor(mv)  
         + as.numeric(min_GCS), ApacheData)
```

and I want to use this model to predict a new input value, so I built a data frame:

```
new <- data.frame(state_today=1, daily_creat=2.3, daily=2 , age=25, apache3=12, mv=1,     min_GCS=20)'
```

Then I call predict:

```
 predict(fit, new , se.fit=TRUE)
```

And I get the error:
     Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
      factor as.factor(daily) has new level 2

I also tried daily=as.factor(2) in data.frame() and I got the same error. Can anyone help me about this?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I get error `Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'ApacheData' not found`. Please make your question reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original data does not have any cases where `ApacheData$daily == 2`. The `lm` object has no coefficient associated with it, so it throws an error.

Comment: Before running this:                                                                  ApacheData$daily <- cut(ApacheData$daily, breaks=c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9,3000))                                                                  I had 3821 rows with daily ==2 in the original data. Is the thing you mentioned happening because of that I use "cut" the daily in different sub groups? If so, is there still any way that I can predict new data while keeping the "cut" code?

Comment: Run `cut(2, breaks=c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9,3000))` to see the labels it produces. You need to run the same function on the new data to ensure consistency of the labels. You can also specify the labels you would like for each level using `cut(..., labels=)`

Comment: When I run     cut(2, breaks=c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9,3000))
I got this: [1] (1,2]
Levels: (-1,0] (0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,9] (9,3e+03]

Comment: Yes, it has automatically generated labels for the intervals. The new data needs to have the same labels, so you should pass `daily` through the same `cut()` function.